# How to preview functions code on pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, greenplum

When I would login into a postgresql database in pgAdmin3 and when I expand a schema I would see a tab for functions. When you click on the functions and select a function you can see the function's code.In pgAdmin 4 I don't see the tab for functions under schema. How can I see the function code in pgAdmin 4?

Comment: ok Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 4):

Click on the function and go to the `Properties` tab:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when i expand the schema i see only 3 options: Tables Types and Views. There is no function or other details.

Comment: Sorry where can i find the log?

Comment: I should also mention that I am trying to connect to greenplum and not postgresql

Comment: In this case I cannot help you. Not familiar with `greenplum`

Comment: I suspect you won't have much success making it work. Not sure if this feature is supported for greenplum. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you. very helpful. but you select sql instead of properties

Answer (score 2):

In the version 2.x  of pgAdmin4 when you connect to a GreenPlum database you will not be able to see Functions/External Tables/Graphical Explain Plans.

We are working with the pgAdmin4 community in order to introduce them in the next release.

Our hope is that in the next couple of weeks the version 3.0 will be released, with it you will be able to see Functions, you will be able to execute Explain and Explain Analyze plans. As we speak we are implementing the External Table part, that we hope will be finalized before 3.0 is released.

Answer (score 0):

The pgAdmin 4 tool is compatible with Pivotal Greenplum Daabase 5.0.0, but is not officially supported by Pivotal. You can use pgAdmin 4 to query Greenplum Database tables and to view Greenplum Database table DDL, but some functionality is either unavailable or not fully implemented when used with Greenplum Database:
Partitioned tables can cause pgAdmin performance to slow down.
External tables are not supported.
Graphical explain analyze is not supported.
Append-optimized tables are expected to work with pgAdmin 4.

Ref: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/500/relnotes/GPDB_500_README.html